# Is it worth it to take the Wild Wasteland trait in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I know that this trait adds some more fun to the game but other than that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Wasteland), there are a number of otherwise unattainable encounters that you can experience if you have the Wild Wasteland trait, including some in the DLCs.

**Number of Wild Wasteland Encounters:**

- "Core" game - 22
- Dead Money - 3
- Honest Hearts - 2
- Old World Blues - 11
- Lonesome Road - 4

These feature references to many popular movies/TV:

- Star Wars
- Indiana Jones
- Lassie

Notable Loot:

- [Alien Blaster](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_blaster_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)) (and 100 [shots](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_power_cell_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)))

Unattainable Loot:

- [YCS/186 unique Gauss Rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/YCS/186) is not available if you have the Wild Wasteland perk (as it is replaced by the Alien Blaster)

**Is it worth it?** That's something only you can decide.

Comment: If I get it right I will have just one YCS/186 unique Gauss Rifle so I won't be able to maintain/repair it anyway and it will blow up eventually, right?

Comment: @AdamArold the unique Gauss Rifle can be repaired using normal gauss rifles, or at vendors that offer that service, or by a weapon repair kit, or by other means if you have the Jury Rigger perk. The Alien Blaster - although it can be repaired, has a limited number of shots, because the ammo cannot be purchased or (to my knowledge) built.

Answer (score 10):

You can read up on the specifics of the trait [on the Fallout Wiki article](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Wasteland).

The biggest difference is trading the unique [Gauss Rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/YCS/186) for a unique [Alien Blaster](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_blaster_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29). I think the Alien Blaster uses special ammo that you only find a very limited supply of while the Gauss Blaster uses MF cells. The Alien Blaster is pretty ridiculous though, zero spread and every shot is a critical. You also miss out on a few mini-nukes.

If you want the perk, get it for the humor. IMO it far outweighs the (fairly minor) gameplay changes, which I'm sure is intentional. It's basically one gun difference, plus a few mininukes, and if you're like me you never even use "too good to use" consumable items like that anyway.

Comment: The mini-nukes are replaced in Wild Wasteland by the Holy Frag Grenades: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Holy_Frag_Grenade

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, if you are the kind that would like/love a good laugh at times, it would be worth it.

Otherwise I don't recommend it considering that 
unique YCS/186 Gauss Rifle is replaced with Alien Blaster when you have this perk.

#### Note:

If you do get the perk, you can get one then the other with console codes on the PC, that would be the only way to get both, considering I have both.

To acquire both of the weapons (and extra ammo for the Alien Blaster), you can use `player.additem item_base_id_here` command.

Fallout wiki articles have the "item codes" ("base id") :

- [YCS/186 Gauss Rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/YCS/186) - `0015b38d`.
- [Alien Blaster](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_blaster_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)) - `00004322`
- [Alien power cell](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_power_cell_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)) (ammo for the blaster) - `00029364`

Comment: I don't mind circumventing stupid limitations so I would definitely use the console thanks!

Comment: @AdamArold I've added more info on how exactly use can obtain these weapons (and APC for blaster) to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I never take it. The Ycs/186 is far more versatile especially outside of vats and with the inclusion of max charge ammo. One to two sneak crits will kill every legendary creature in the game. You can also use scrounger and the brotherhood ammo reward crate in hidden valley to get 100+ ammo every few days. It is the ultimate sniper platform in the game and the unique laser pistol Pew Pew with the high crit chance attainable for laser weaponry through perks and challenges is comparable to the Alien Blaster in terms of killing power.

Answer (score -1):

simply put, "wild wasteland" tickles your wrinkled little brains, while it's absence does not. Either way, you'll eventually be an overpowered demi-god, so an additional char buff perk doesn't ultimately add nuff. 
Some use the YCS as an argument...well, the gun is nothing much, really. The .50 is better in terms of rate of fire, explosive ammo option, 'friendly' scope and suppression. 
The trait adds content. A DLC of sorts, but without the 'D' So why not. You'll still kick ass. FFS, Vegas is accessible on level 1 and you're being picky about some damn trait as if it's a life-and-death matter.

Comment: This answer adds nothing not covered in more detail, aside from complaining about the question.

Comment: These are actually good points, even if the tone could be friendlier. You can beat this game with a 10mm pistol if you want. I've done it without killing *anyone*.

Answer (score -2):

Well there's a glitch that allows you to use any ammo for the alien blaster so its definitely worth it. equip a weapon you have alot of ammo for and hold the hot key button dont let go goto ammo and equip that ammo under a hot key and boom more then 100 bullets for the alien blaster

Answer (score -2):

I think the trait is good if you like to have a good time and don't care about the serious tone that immerses you into the game. I f you want to play the game properly and complete the main mission and all, then the trait might not be for you. But if you don't really care about the quests and just want to wander the mojave to just see what you stumble across, then you might want it.